# File similiar to nbactions.xml for intellij

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, netbeans

In my company we are working with NetBeans IDE.

I was trying to switch to intellij as I prefer it as an editor over NetBeans, but the big problem seems to be the lack of Maven integration as it is in NetBeans.

I was trying to find a similar solution for the file nbactions.xml that is for NetBeans in intellij, and have come up short.

Is there any solution as to configuring a file for the actions to be taken upon build, run and debug as in the nbactions.xml file?

(I know of ways to edit configuration directly in the project, I am looking for one configured file that intellij would be able to parse such as NetBeans parses the nbactions.xml file).

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

What I want to do is have a configuration of specific phases to be executed when I click build, run, build with dependencies, etc.

For example, I can write a file that will look like this:

```
<actions>
    <action>
        <actionName>rebuild</actionName>
        <preAction>build-with-dependencies</preAction>
        <packagings>
            <packaging>*</packaging>
        </packagings>
        <goals>
            <goal>clean</goal>
            <goal>package</goal>
            <goal>assembly:single</goal>
        </goals>
    </action>
    <action>
        <actionName>run</actionName>
        <packagings>
            <packaging>jar</packaging>
        </packagings>
        <goals>
            <goal>process-classes</goal>
            <goal>org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec</goal>
        </goals>
        <properties>
            <exec.args>-classpath %classpath org.bgu.ddms.node.Main</exec.args>
            <exec.executable>java</exec.executable>
        </properties>
    </action>
    <action>
        <actionName>debug</actionName>
        <packagings>
            <packaging>jar</packaging>
        </packagings>
        <goals>
            <goal>process-classes</goal>
            <goal>org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec</goal>
        </goals>
        <properties>
            <exec.args>-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=n,address=${jpda.address} -classpath %classpath org.bgu.ddms.node.Main</exec.args>
            <exec.executable>java</exec.executable>
            <jpda.listen>true</jpda.listen>
        </properties>
    </action>
    <action>
        <actionName>profile</actionName>
        <packagings>
            <packaging>jar</packaging>
        </packagings>
        <goals>
            <goal>process-classes</goal>
            <goal>org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec</goal>
        </goals>
        <properties>
            <exec.args>-classpath %classpath org.bgu.ddms.node.Main</exec.args>
            <exec.executable>java</exec.executable>
        </properties>
    </action>
    <action>
        <actionName>build</actionName>
        <preAction>build-with-dependencies</preAction>
        <packagings>
            <packaging>*</packaging>
        </packagings>
        <goals>
            <goal>install</goal>
        </goals>
    </action>
    <action>
        <actionName>clean</actionName>
        <preAction>build-with-dependencies</preAction>
        <packagings>
            <packaging>*</packaging>
        </packagings>
        <goals>
            <goal>clean</goal>
        </goals>
    </action>
</actions>
```

Which, when I do any desired action written above, executes the associated goals

Comment: You'd better explain what you're trying to achieve, without just saying "like ngactions does in NetBeans", because IntelliJ users probably know how to achieve what you want, but don't use NetBeans and have thus no idea of what nbactions is.

Comment: @JBNizet added, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a "Run configuration" and make sure you check the "Share" checkbox at the top.

That will create an xml file under `.idea/runConfigurations`, that you can store in your VCS, and thus share with your colleagues.

IntelliJ will automatically find and read those files and add the corresponding "Run configurations".

Comment: Thanks! Funny I couldn't find anything about this file anywhere